# ANSIBLE: using variables on a hosts file (ssh)

Tags: variables, ansible

I´m newbie with this fantastic automation engine, and have a little issue with the vars file:

By the momment, I must connect via SSH without keypars using an specifics users and password.

**hosts file**

```
[all:vars]
connection_mode1=ssh 
ssh_user1=user1
ssh_pass1=pass1

[serverstest]
host1 ansible_connection=connection_mode1 ansible_ssh_user=ssh_user1 ansible_ssh_pass=ssh_pass1
```

I'm also trying wrap with "" and {} but doesn't works.

How can I use variables on this parameters?

Comment: why not just define `ansible_connection` and other params in `[all:vars]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ansible_ssh_user` has been deprecated since v. 2.0. It becomes `ansible_user`. See [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html).

Never store `ansible_ssh_pass` variable in plain text; always use a vault. See [Variables and Vaults](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults).

Anyway, having a `mytest.inventory` file as follows

```
[all:vars]
ssh_user1=user1

[serverstest]
host1 ansible_user="{{ ssh_user1 }}"
```

it works, e.g.

```
ansible -i mytest.inventory serverstest -m ping -k
```

Option `-k` asks for the password.

If you still want to write the password in the inventory you can leave the password variable definition and add `ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass1 }}"`

```
[serverstest]
192.168.15.201 ansible_user="{{ ssh_user1 }}" ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass1 }}"
```

Comment: thank you! I´m only testing the possibilities in a lab´environment to implement this solutions. By the momment, the security has not a high priority but your appointment is gratefully accepted :)

Im test the following 

  `[all:vars]
  ssh_user1=user
  ssh_pass1=password
  [serverstest]
  machine1 ansible_ssh_user="{{ ssh_user1 }}" ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass1 }}"
  machine2 ansible_user="{{ ssh_user1 }}" ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass1 }}"`

Comment: Right comment:


Im test the following 


  `[all:vars]



  ssh_user1=user


  ssh_pass1=password


  [serverstest]


  machine1 ansible_ssh_user="{{ ssh_user1 }}" ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass1 }}"


  machine2 ansible_user="{{ ssh_user1 }}" ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass1 }}"`


the machine 2 (without "ssh" in the user) not works. But it doesn´t matter

Thank you so much for your feedback

Comment: May be it depends from the Ansible version. If it is less than 2.0 anslibe_ssh_user is right.